# What is the duration for the App Engine task queue tombstones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Recently I got TombstonedTaskError and I would like to know what is the duration for the TombstonedTaskError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TombstonedTaskError` is raised if you're attempting to enqueue a named task using a name that has been used recently, see [What is TombstonedTaskError from App Engine's Task Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102660/4495081).

The duration of the de-duplication logic has been documented since that answer was posted. From [Naming a task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#naming_a_task) (emphasis mine):

> When you create a new task, App Engine assigns the task a unique name
>   by default. However, you can assign your own name to a task by using
>   the name parameter. An advantage of assigning your own task names is
>   that named tasks are de-duplicated, which means you can use task names
>   to guarantee that a task is only added once. **De-duplication
>   continues for 9 days after the task is completed or deleted**.